# Java: Network Statistics of running Java App from inside App itself

Tags: java, networking, benchmarking

Is there a way to monitor the network traffic (bytes transferred, packet count) from inside the java program itself?

I want to benchmark a third party application (IBM Domino DIIOP). There is no way to pass a custom network socket etc. to the library. The benchmark app is running on windows/Linux. Right now I'm doing the monitoring with Wireshark, but it's complicated and time-consuming. Wireshark negatively influences the network performance, so it's not the perfect choice for benchmarking.

Is there a pure java solution which works on Windows and/or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to monitor the network traffic from inside the java program itself?

There are several ways:

1. You can monitor sockets. Please refer to the following [article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue169.html). Also there is a number of libraries on the internet.
2. You can use runtime weaving with AspectJ to intercept calls with AOP and calculate statistics.

Still you should keep in mind that not all statistics can be collected from application in general. Network communication is delegated to OS and application is generally not aware of transport details.

> bytes transferred

You can calculate bytes read and written by the app but not the actual amount of bytes transmitted over network.

> packet count

Packet count is not available from application as it is responsibility of network protocol driver to form and deliver packets.